# Eth0 Interface always down when restarting (

Tags: networking, kali-linux

The version of Kali Linux I am using is Linux kali 6.0.0-kali6-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.0.12-1kali
I am using vmware pro.

When I type in IP a, I get this as the output for my ETH0 interface

```
eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:6a:d7:30 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

When I type in these two commands, an IP address gets assigned

```
ip link set dev eth0 up
dhclient -v eth0
```

Shouldn't this be automatic? Whats going on here.

Answer (score 1):

To have the network interface start up on boot, which I assume is meant by the term "automatic", it needs to be configured to do so using a network configuration program like ifupdown, NetworkManager, systemd-networkd or another.

From Kali docs:

"Network services disabled by default: Kali Linux contains systemd hooks that disable network services by default. These hooks allow us to install various services on Kali Linux, while ensuring that our distribution remains secure by default, no matter what packages are installed. Additional services such as Bluetooth are also blocklisted by default."
See: https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/

So you need to choose a configuration tool and configure it.
This Debian page has examples: https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration